# Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008

Situation:

I have two systems, one (System 1) is configured with `Windows 2008` Server and it also has active directory configuration. I also created a user named as user1 in it.
           The second system (System 2) is a windows 7 and it is under the domain of windows server. 
I also installed Microsoft `Visual Studio 2010` in it.

*My question is:*

```
   I logged into the windows 7 system with domain user user1 and its password.
```

Then the Opened visual studio, in server explorer -> Data Connections -> Add Connection

I gave the server name as system1\sqlexpress, using windows authentication and selected master table. When I click the test connection button it gave " Test Connection Succeeded" message.

Then I tried to create a table in this connection that time got a message

> " You are not logged on as the database owner, or system
>   administrator. You Might not be able to save changes to tables that
>   you do not own  Certain edits require CREATE TABLE permission"

How To solve this Problem?????

Comment: "configured with Windows 2008 Server and it also has active directory configuration" - worth editing either it "Windows Server 2008 with AD DS role installed" (you installed & configured AD DS role on it, effectively making it a DC) or "Windows Server 2008 domain member" (joined to existing domain along with your workstation). As I'm not sure about your configuration I can't edit it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the database is a different set of permissions that CREATE permissions in a database.

The simplest way would be to add your login to sql, then add you as the administrator/owner of the database.

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'[<domainName>\<login_name>]'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.     Then Where i Type the above line of code in my windows system. Waiting for reply

Answer (score 0):

By default when you are installing SQL server, account under which you installed it gets **SA role**, which has full access to this SQL server and databases hosted on it.
Obviously you are using another account when you are connecting to server from Win7 machine. Your connectivity tests are OK because by default after SQL server installation BUILTIN\Users get **Public** SQL server role - so you can read and connect but nothing more with such rights (by default).
So you should grant more rights to your **User1**: either on a SQL server or on a particular database level. This can be done either through GUI or SQL commands as suggested in answer by @Barry Colebank Jr. In both ways you would use **SQL Server Management Studio** to connect to your SQL server and then either add new user and grant him SA role on SQL server level (see screenshot below) or use script/GUI for granting rights on DB level (select DB in the tree and select New Query from its context menu).

[image]

As for GUI way to do it: first you add user, then go to Roles tab & check role you want to assign to this user. 
P.S. SQL Server Management Studio either included with SQL Server version you installed or can be downloaded separately from Microsoft. For example here is the link for [SQL Server Management Studio 2012 download](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPMS/enus/) from Microsoft.